# Use Regex to Allow 3 Underscores Maximum

Tags: php, regex

```
'@^([^\W_]*\s){0,3}[^\W_]*$@'
```

I need to allow 3 underscores.

The above regex matches:

English alphanumeric
3 spaces
Doesn't allow underscores
Doesn't allow special characters

I want it to match:

English alphanumeric
3 spaces max.
***Allow 3 underscores max.***
Doesn't allow special characters

Here is my attempt:

1.

```
'@^([^\W]*_\s){0,3}[^\W]*$@'
```

2.

```
'@^([^\W]*\s){0,3}([^\W]*_){0,3}[^\W]*$@'
```

Both of my attempts don't work.

I use the regex in php (preg_match function) ...
No specific order.

```
if(preg_match('@^([^\W_]*\s){0,3}[^\W_]*$@', $_POST['txt_username_reg']))
```

Data match:

james_arden 20
james arden 20
James_arden_20_done

Data don't match:

hello james arden done 20 (reason: 4 spaces)
what_is_your_name_done (reason: 4 underscores)
testing123? (reason: special chars)

Comment: `I need to allow 3 underscores` - doesn't really explain the question. Later you say `Allow me to put unlimited number of _` - which is it? Whats the source data, whats the desired output?

Comment: A couple of examples would be of *great help* here: one example of **data that should match** and one of **data that should NOT match**.

Comment: Does the underscores need to be contiguous ?

Comment: No the underscores doesn't have to be contagious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches any string containing 3 or less underscores:

```
^[^_]*(_[^_]*){0,3}$
```

And this matches any string containing exactly 3 underscores:

```
^[^_]*(_[^_]*){3}$
```

### EDIT

To support Arabic letters, try something like this:

```
'/^[^_]*(_[^_]*){0,3}$/u'
```

note the use of the `u` modifier:

> **u** (PCRE8)
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.
>
> -- http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: The regex has to support Arabic letters. I tried /p{Arabic}, it didn't work..........preg_match('@^([^\W_]*\s){0,3}([^_]*(_[^_]*)){0,3}[^\W_]*/p{Arabic}$@'

Comment: Look similar, but not the same ... The arabic version is little bit above the underscore

Comment: @tchrist: I think that's the point: PCRE doesn't treat the target string as UTF-8 unless you tell it to.  And even then, PCRE's Unicode support is not as complete as Perl's.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use a regular expressions, just use [`substr_count`](http://php.net/substr_count):

```
$lessThan3Underscores = substr_count($input, '_') <= 3;
```

If there is some absurd reason why you must use an regular expression (which will be harder to read and therefore, harder to maintain), match against

```
^[^_]*(_[^_]*){0,3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to post a separate answer for the sake of a different approach.

Rather than build a complex regex that keeps count, just allow infinitely many underscores... then run another regex after that and make sure there is at most 3 underscores. Can greatly simplify more complicated conditions.

PS. Got beaten to it by @phihag